# Android: AnimationSet with multiple animations

Tags: android

When I start the animation with just 1 animation (e.g. slideDownAnimation) then it works perfect. Once I add the second animation, the view gets invisible.

```
animationSet.addAnimation(slideDownAnimation);
animationSet.addAnimation(slideUpAnimation);
view.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

slidedown.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="3000"/>
```

slideup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="3000"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried merging the two XML files into one? Look at the docs on how to do it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a single animator:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" 
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="3000" />
    <set android:startOffset="3000">
        <translate 
            android:fromYDelta="100%p" 
            android:toYDelta="0%p"
            android:duration="3000" />
    </set>
</set>
```

I believe both animations are running simultaneously right now. By using the `startOffset` property in the animation set, it won't happen.